# 2.4 ghz RF radio and antenna - nrf24 underneath a 7-segment display

Tags: rf, 7segmentdisplay, nrf24l01

[image]

1. I have this tiny nrf24 module that I want to use underneath a 7-segment display.
   How much will this affect the range and the quality of the radio signal?

[image]

2. I have done a lot of research and testing on this other similar nrf24 module. Mostly about modifying the antenna to get a better signal/range, but unfortunately, none of those mods really do anything. Since then I went back, read more and found out that the antenna design in these nrf24 module are called Meandered Inverted-F Antenna (MIFA), which means it is the already a good design and trying to modify it is a bad idea? After done my own homework, I am able to get twice the range than before, and I am pretty happy about it, but longer is always better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These nrf24 modules use the 2.4 GHz ISM band. The wavelength of such a signal is around 12 cm. Antennas get useful when longer than one quarter of that so in this case 3 cm. That is in the order of the length of that meander. You adding wires to it actually **makes the antenna perform worse !**

At 2.5 GHz you cannot do much with standard wires. You could disconnect the meander on the module (there is probably a resistor or capacitor feeding the signal to the antenna) and use an antenna for Wifi instead. Note that these will have a small [coax cable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coaxial_cable) to feed the signal to the antenna. These are quite small and hard to solder properly. Some experience is required ! Then mount that Wifi antenna somewhere where it has some space around it.

It is hard to predict what range you will get when mounting the module between other modules. Anything containing electrically conductive structures will harm the effectiveness of the antenna. It is always a good idea to give the antenna some space to "breathe".

Comment: That and, close proximity of other circuitry to active RF radiation can (in poorly-designed circuitry) lead to [very strange behavior](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-13Q-UsXKQM).

Comment: I have seen wifi antenna with very long cable. won't those cable acts as antenna in that case? I have an idea about adding my own MIFA antenna on the pcb and and connect the signal from the nrf24 to my pcb's antenna. but doing so, won't it deteriorate the quality of the antenna with the added wiring?

Comment: You can use a very long cable to an antenna but realize that the signal is at 2.4 GHz so the cable must be suited for that. Such cables will always be coaxial, RG316 is a suitable one. You cannot simply **add** an antenna, to do that properly you would need to antenna switches and amplifiers. These need to be 2 way as the antenna is used for transmitting and receiving. You cannot simply add an antenna in parallel as that destroys the 50 ohms characteristic impedance of the system.

Comment: That also means that you will **make things worse** if you "just add wires" and do not do things in the proper "RF" (radio frequency) way. I suggest not to mess with it as it will bring you **nothing**. You have to learn how to work with 2.4 GHz signals. Even very experienced EEs who do not work with RF signals consider RF signals and how to work with them a **black art**. I don't because I have 20 years of experience in RF ;-) (the magic has worn off a bit).

Answer (score 1):

Your should not try to modify the embedded antenna, since it is already optimized for maximum emission. What you can do is to DETACH the antenna (cut it off, or cut it from another board), and connect the board to the antenna with a tiny coaxial 50-Ohm cable, then place the antenna outside your electronic components. You will need to identify/guess where the RF board has the 50-Ohm output network, and where the antenna 50-ohm input is. Or you can try to make your own antenna at the end of coax cable, but the old PCB antenna should be disconnected.